# Import Python Module to Class Variable

Tags: python

I am trying to import a class in Python and after importing the class set a class variable as the imported class. I have searched Google as well as stackoverflow for an answer to this, but have not been able to find one.

For Example:

DB.py:

```
class DB:
    def __init__(self):
        #init sets up the db connection

    def FetchAll():
        #Fetchall fetches all records from database
```

Ex.py:

```
class Ex:
    def __init__(self):
        import DB.py as DB
        self.db = DB.DB()

    def FetchAll(self):
        result_set = self.db.FetchAll()
```

I would like to be able to access the FetchAll() in the DB class from Ex class through a variable. I know in PHP this is possible by using "Protected" keyword in a class.

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: First, you can't `import DB.py`; just `import DB`. And there's no need for an `as` if you want the name it already has. However, this whole design is almost certainly a bad idea. Why do you want to `import` the module in the middle of your class, instead of at the top of your module, as usual?

Comment: To access the `FetchAll` method, just access it: `self.db.FetchAll()`, exactly as you've written. There is no such thing as "protected" in Python; everything is accessible by everyone.

Comment: I got used to importing files as needed in PHP, in an effort to optimize code (it may not have been actually optimized but it was standard practice from my last development job)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just

```
import DB
```

You provide a module name (that can be located given the current module search path), not a file name.

Check [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) for a beginner’s overview of how modules and imports work.

Comment: this in combination with the above helped me out. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can either just use the name of the class as the class variable:

```
import DB

class Ex:
    # define methods
    # call FetchAll with DB.FetchAll()
```

Or create a new class variable with the 'as' key:

```
import DB as x

class Ex:
    # define methods
    # call FetchAll with x.FetchAll()
```

And like the others are saying, import all modules at the top of the script.